# density inequality in metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am given a metric space $(X,d)$ s.t. $Y\subseteq X$ is dense in $X$. Moreover, I have $U$ an open set in $X$. Is the statement $d(U\cap Y)\leq d(U)$ is true? It seems so, but I cannot seem to be able to prove it. If not, does anybody have a counter example? Thanks for the help.

Notation: $d(K)$ is the smallest cardinality of a dense subset of $K$.

Comment: What is meant by $d(U\cap Y)$ and $d(U)$?

Comment: $d(U)$ is the smallest cardinality of dense subset of $U$

Comment: In a metric space $d(A) = w(A)$ for all subsets, where $w(A)$ is the minimal cardinality of a base, as usual; and for weight the inequality is obvious.

Comment: It seems more logical that $d$ would denote the diameter, maybe?

Comment: this is the notation I was taught at the university. I am not aware of a different notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any metric (metrizable) space, the density and weight<sup>*</sup> cardinal functions are equal. Furthermore, the weight cardinal function is monotone with respect to subspaces (for general topological spaces). As any subspace of a metric space is metric, we have: $$d ( U \cap Y ) = w ( U \cap Y ) \leq w ( U ) = d ( U ).$$

<sup>*</sup>The *weight* $w(X)$ of a topological space $X$ is the smallest cardinality of a base for $X$.

Comment: Just to make sure, are we using the notation for d(..) as I mentioned above?

Comment: Started typing this before I saw [Henno Brandsma's comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1498195/density-inequality-in-metric-space/1498200#comment3051639_1498195) to the question. Sorry if this was inappropriate.

Comment: @User666x Yes, $d(.)$ denotes the density of the topological space (smallest cardinality of a dense subset).

Comment: Well, thank you very much! :)